# Jump in a parabolic arc with the cursor as the vertex

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using unity and I'm trying to get an object (a ball with a 2D rigid body and box collider) to jump in a perfect parabola with the peak of the arc being the cursors position.

I have gotten to the point where the ball will jump in the right direction and stuff but I cant figure out how to get it to fluctuate the force properly based on the cursors position. I've tried a few different things and this is the closest I have gotten. Can anybody help me out?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ballController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isJumping = false;
    private Vector2 startPos;
    private Vector2 endPos;  
    private Vector2 vertex;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.gravityScale = 1.25f;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !isJumping)
        {

            startPos = rb.position;


            Vector2 cursorPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            
            vertex = new Vector2((startPos.x + cursorPosition.x) / 2f, Mathf.Max(startPos.y, cursorPosition.y) + 1f);

            endPos.y = startPos.y;
            endPos.x = startPos.x + (vertex.x * 2);

            Vector2 direction = startPos - vertex;
            float distance = Mathf.Clamp(Vector2.Distance(vertex, startPos), 0f, 1.5f);
            float forceMagnitude = distance * -500f;

            rb.AddForce((direction.normalized * forceMagnitude), 0f);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you need a few kinematic equations, so strap in for some math.

Maximum height of projectile: [image: formula]

Time to reach maximum height: [image: formula]

Maximum distance of projectile: [image: formula]

Maximum height is the delta y between your starting position and the cursors position. Maximum distance is twice the delta x between the start amd cursor postion. G is the gravitational acceleration that you can easily get from the physics engine.

By solving these equations for their velocity components you get:
[image: formula] and [image: formula]. Since we can get half the max distance for free, we can adjust the formula for the horizontal velocity component to be [image: formula].

Now we can implement the formulas with code. Instead of two floats for d and h, I'm using a single `Vector2` called delta. X axis is half the max distance h and Y is the max height. Unless you're doing something weird with the gravity you're probably going to have a negative y value for g. That's a problem when you calculate a square root, so it's important to use the absolute value. Since the code would fail with the root if the user clicks below the ball, this also has to be stopped.

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BallController : MonoBehaviour
{
  private Rigidbody2D rb;
  private bool isJumping;

  void Start()
  {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.gravityScale = 1.25f;
  }

  void FixedUpdate()
  {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !isJumping)
    {
      Vector2 cursorPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
      Vector2 delta = cursorPosition - rb.position;
      if (delta.y < 0)
      {
        isJumping = true;
        float adjustedGravity = Mathf.Abs(Physics2D.gravity.y) * rb.gravityScale;
        Vector2 velocity = Vector2.zero;

        velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(2 * delta.y * adjustedGravity);
        velocity.x = (delta.x * adjustedGravity) / velocity.y;
        rb.velocity = velocity;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Due to the way the physics are implemented in Unity you might notice a small deviation at large distances and long throw durations.